# How can I assign ColorDialog.Color to another form in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, colordialog

I am trying to assign the color value returned from `ColorDialog` on one form to another form.

Form 1 consists of 2 buttons: 'Place Order' (creates a new form with bunch of controls) and 'Select Color' (allows you to change the color of Place Order form). So you can't have Place Order and Select Color open at the same time.

Therefore, I somehow must reference the `BackColor` property of the Place Order form to form that has the two buttons so that `ColorDialog.Color` can be assigned to the Place Order form.

Form1 Code:

```
private void SelectColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string color = Convert.ToString(colorDialog1.Color);
        MessageBox.Show(color);
        this.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color; // BackColor is only accessible for this form
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and explain where is the other form, you only show Form1, where is Form2 and how do you load it?

Comment: The real question is, why isn't the "Select Color" button on the "Place Order" form? Considering that it directly affects this form, it doesn't make much sense that it isn't physically located on that form. This would also make your job a lot easier, because you wouldn't have to either maintain a variable indicating the selected color or an instance of the "Place Order" form in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing this, you will need to maintain a variable to hold the color. Do it like this:

```
//Declare this private variable to hold the color selected by the user
private System.Drawing.Color selectedcolor;    

private void SelectColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        selectedcolor = colorDialog1.Color; // BackColor stored in variable
    }
}
```

then in the code where you launch your new form (Place order button) put this:

```
private void PlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I am assuming PlaceOrderForm is the name of the class of your other form
    PlaceOrderForm frm = new PlaceOrderForm();
    //Initialize other properties and events,etc.
    //Then make its background color as selected by user
    if(selectedcolor != null) frm.BackColor = selectedcolor;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but I'm not sure why you've shown code to convert the selected color to a `string`. I suppose that was for the `MessageBox` call that you've now commented out; perhaps the line above it should be commented as well.

Comment: yeah i forgot to comment that one..just removed it all

Answer (score 0):

```
if(colorDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) {return;}

form2 f = new form2();
f.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
f.Show();
```